# Are the verbs Take and Bring considered antonyms?

Tags: verbs

Take this with you. Vs. Bring this to me.
What should I take? vs, What should I bring?

To me the verb, take and bring are antonyms of different directions. Am I correct?

which is correct in a occation where I ask someone about what to pack for a camping trip? 
What should I take? vs. What should I bring?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say they are direct antonyms.

*Give* and *Take* would be considered antonyms. They are opposing actions.

*Take* and *Bring* are more indicative when you should actually possess the item, although subtle:

> Take a torch with you

Have a torch in your possession when you leave.

In this instance it's not strictly necessary to still have the item when you arrive at your destination - '*Take a drink with you*' - you can drink this on the journey

> Bring a torch with you

Have a torch in your possession when you arrive.

When you arrive, you need to have this item with you - '*Bring a drink with you*' - You don't need to have this when you leave (your house for example) but by the time you arrive, you need to have it (You could pick a drink up in a shop on the way)

For a list of items for camping - the two can usually be used *synonymously* though.